# Assigning image to tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios5

### I am trying to show image in an imageView inside table cell. Name of Image I pull from web service and then put it in object's property which is NSString type.

```
//Get image corresponding to row index from array
Visitors *tmp = [allItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

//This works perfectly


     [[cell textLabel] setText:[tmp fName]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[tmp flagName]];



    NSString *pathToImage = [tmp flagName];

//This prints correct image file name, like usflag.gif
   NSLog(@"%@ ",pathToImage);

//This shows images in each cell
    cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"usflag.gif"];

//This shows nothing
    cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:pathToImage];
```

Could somebody please explain why it can't read image and what is correct way to make it work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error has most likely to do with the names of your images. `imageNamed` will only return an image if an image file of the same name is found in the application's bundle. Check for every single one if these image files are present. Be careful with the spelling.

Comment: I checked file names it all correct. Also if I put explicit string , like @"immagename.gif" imageNamed works but imageWithContentsOfFile doesn't. Any thoughts? Thank.

Comment: Are you mixing `imageWithContentsOfFile` and `imageNamed`? That would explain your error. `imageWithContentsOfFile` requires a full or partial path.

Comment: No, I am not mixing, I just tried them both. I think I see where problem is(hopefuly). Image path returned from object has \n at the end. Not sure yet how to fix and if it's a problem, but at least some light ahead :)

Comment: Yes,it was a problem. Besides newline char I had several white spaces appended to a file path. After removing everything went OK. Mundi, thanks a lot for help.